# Can we find the relationship between $I$, $J$ and $K$ if $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in I$, $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x\in J$, and $f^2(x)>g^2(x)$ for $x\in K$?

Tags: inequality

## Edit

I am trying to solve inequalities with absolute values  and/or radical operators. I know that

> Non negative $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ and $a(x)\leq b(x)$ in a certain domain $I$ can be represented as  $a^2(x)\leq b^2(x)$ without causing the changes in their domain.

For example, $|2x-1|>|x+1|$ can be solved by rewriting it as $(2x-1)^2>(x+1)^2$.

However, $|2x-1|>x-5$ for example, cannot be rewritten as $(2x-1)^2>(x-5)^2$ because the original domain has changed.

Can we find the relationship between $I$, $J$ and $K$ if $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in I$, $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x\in J$, and $f^2(x)>g^2(x)$ for $x\in K$ ? I am expecting I can find $J$ in terms of $I$ and $K$ to solve $f(x)>g(x)$.

Comment: One thing for sure $J\cap K\subset I$.

Comment: What kind of relation are you looking for?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe: For example,  $J=I\cap K$.